# Why doesn't CORFU the Distributed Shared Log validate deletes?

Tags: algorithm, consensus, paxos

The paper [CORFU: A Distributed Shared Log](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2535930) presents the protocol in psudeo code which doesn't validate delete messages. To quote the paper:

```
Upon <delete,addr> request:
  mark addr deleted
  respond ack
```

This means that we can delete pages that have yet to be written. It also means that clients can delete pages using an out of date cluster configuration. Doesn't this mean that the protocol as presented in the paper can lose deletes?

According to the paper CORFU keeps a high watermark of deleted addresses as a memory space optimisation. If we can lose deletes that high watermark won't move and we will bleed memory.

If we use CORFU for state machine replication we can snapshot the state machine and delete the log up to the snapshot. If we can lose deletes then the log will actually grow forever.

Rather than just applying the delete without validation wouldn't an implementation simply make deletes idempotent yet validate them as follows:

```
Upon <delete,epoch,addr> request:
  if epoch != s.epoch respond err_sealed
  else respond according to addr status: 
       if written mark addr deleted, <ack>
       if available, <err_unwritten>
       if deleted, <ack>
```

Or would that harm safety or performance in some way?

Comment: I spoke to the 1st and 2nd authors by email and they confirmed that I am correct that in a general implementation deletes should be protected by an epoch check. The specific implementation described in pseudo code treated deletes as best efforts which wasn't a problem for the specific applications that implementation was built for. When I get some time I will answer my own question with more details.